# CLion can't compile new project

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, clion

I've recently encontered a problem with CLion. Every time I create a new project the following error appears on the console:

```
C:\Users\Diego\.CLion2018.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/cygwin64/bin/make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:/cygwin64/bin/c++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" "/cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/build.make.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/depend.make.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/flags.make.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/link.txt.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Could not create /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/DependInfo.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_da27f.dir/progress.make.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.10.3/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:37 (try_compile):
  Failed to generate test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/Diego/Documents/Arquitectura de Computadores/Mini Tareas/Mini Tarea 6/compilador/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It only happend with new c++ projects, the old ones work just fine. I've tried uninstalling CLion, but it didn't work.

Comment: Windows ACL permissions on `C:\Users\Diego\.CLion2018.1` are likely incompatible with cygwin ACL usage. Restart putting the source under the cygwin tree. For example you can use `/usr/src/`. In addition your `Arquitectura de Computadores` include spaces in the name and that is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the compiler too. Also, check out the log files it shows in the last two lines of output and see if there is any more useful information there.

Comment: Do you have any other IDE you can create a c++ project in? If so does it have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I used vim and it worked perfectly. Algo compiling using g++ worked. I noticed that if I opened CLion as admin, everything compiled and there were no errors.